# Communication between two pc...one as server & one as client...using python & kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I am doing final semester training of my B.Tech curriculum & i am making a client & server android application using kivy & python. I have built a client & server kivy application using python. Both codes runs successfully when i am running them on one single pc..but while running them on two different pcs i am getting an error 10054 (An existing connection was forcibly closed by remote host)...for providing internet facility...at server side i am using LAN & at client side i am using Dongle...
Thank you all in advance for your advice

Comment: Sounds like a network issue.

Comment: I have tried to overcome network issue with help of modifying ip address..but then both server & client does nothing..simply it does not respond..can you please help to overcome this...@RyanP

Comment: Using wireshark i have checked that at client side the packet is being sent but at server side's wireshark i am not getting anything related to that packet...i have used port 80 for transmission & QUIC (Quick UDP internet connection) protocol is shown at client side's wireshark

Comment: When using server & client in same network & in different networks..both time server & client works but when i am running server code in pc & client code in my laptop...it doesn't work...server (pc) is having wired LAN & client (laptop) is having Dongle...

Comment: My first guess would be the dongle. Especially if it is a mobile broadband (4G/3G) dongle. Make sure there aren't general connectivity issues with the dongle, and that the network it uses isn't blocking connections or UDP traffic.

Comment: It is a 3G Dongle...how to check the connectivity issues???...@RyanP

Comment: Same problem occurs when i replace 3G Dongle with Portable Wi-Fi Hotspot at client side...